# In function implementation of interface

Tags: c++

In Java, if I have an interface, I can do something like this:

```
blah.setOnClickListner(new OnClickListner() {
     public void clicked() { // do something }
}
```

Can I do something similar in C++?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++ supports local classes.  The syntax is the same as for any class type, except that member functions and static member variables must be defined inside the class body, not declared and defined later (there's no way to name the member from outside the enclosing function).

Beginning in C++11, they can be used as template type parameters, which makes them much much more useful.

It would look something like:

```
void Parent::func( EventProducer* blah )
{
    struct LocalListener : OnClickListener
    {
        virtual void clicked() { ... }
    };
    struct FancyLocalListener : OnClickListener
    {
        Parent* p;
        FancyLocalListener(Parent* p) : p(p) {} // but use better variable names, please ;)
        virtual void clicked() { p->func2(); }
    };

    blah->addOnClickListener(new LocalListener());
    blah->addOnClickListener(new FancyLocalListener(this));
}
```

(but watch out for leaks)

C++ tends not to use interfaces for this, though.  A better design is to accept a functor for the listener, which in C++11 allows the use of lambdas (the compiler creates the local class for you).

Comment: how can I use local variables belonging to the super class?

Comment: Sorry... reading in diagonal... should give another +1, but I cannot :)

Comment: @ComputerEngineer88: A derived class does not *belong* to the base class, it *extends*. Whether the class is local or not is an unrelated issue and will not affect you.

Comment: I want to be able to call member functions of the class func belongs to in LocalListener. Right now, it would require them to be static to use inside clicked().

Comment: @ComputerEngineer88: Give `LocalListener` a constructor, use `new LocalListener(this)` when creating it.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: What does this part do next to the constructor: ": p(p) {}"?

Comment: @ComputerEngineer88: It copies the parameter `p` into the member variable `p`, so that the `Parent*` can be found when the virtual function is called later during event handling.

Comment: ohhh right. i got confused because its the same variable. that works :). You can also have "static Parent* p = this;" on top of FancyLocalListener and it will be able to access it because p is static.

Comment: @ComputerEngineer88: If there's only one instance, finding it is a lot easier.  The code I showed allows you to have many different `Parent` instances and find the right one.  A `static` variable won't.